# Why MySQL workbench is creating incorrect syntax for FULLTEXT index?

Tags: mysql

I am creating `index` using MySQL workbench and the resulting `create` statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`location` (
  `location_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`),
  FULLTEXT INDEX `name_fulltext` USING BTREE (`name` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

But this gave me error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE (`name` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 8
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `ofloy`.`location`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ofloy`.`location` (
          `location_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`),
          FULLTEXT INDEX `name_fulltext` USING BTREE (`name` ASC))
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

If I change the `FULLTEXT` index as: `FULLTEXT (name)`, everything works fine. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

But why workbench is creating the wrong syntax? I checked the mysql version Model is using(from Model > Model options > MySQL) and that's my server default `8.0.12`.

Workbench version: `6.3.10`

Answer (score 2):

Remove Index type `USING BTREE` It is incorrect Syntax type for FullText Index.

BTREE is an index type:

`index_type
    USING {BTREE | HASH}`

index_type is used for normal Index

```
{INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (key_part,...)
      [index_option] ...
```

Correct Syntax for FULLTEXT INDEX is mentioned below:

```
{FULLTEXT|SPATIAL} [INDEX|KEY] [index_name] (key_part,...)
      [index_option] ...
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html#create-table-indexes-keys

Run Below Query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`location` (
  `location_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`),
   FULLTEXT INDEX `name_fulltext`(`name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: `FULLTEXT` index cannot have order defined. Remove `ASC` and it will work fine. Actually, this is a bug in workbench 6.3.10 which set the order by default. Latest releases have resolved it, I haven't verified it yet, but read it on https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91419

Comment: @TheCoder Thanks for the information, I didn't aware about it hence I were mention  that But now I have removed the `ASC`